How to prevent custom field being indexed in custom entity?
I'm creating custom entities extending ContentEntityBase but when I review the created table in MySQL, it has created indexes from fields I don't want. This is and excerpt of my custom entity:
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
        ->setLabel(t('ID'))
        ->setDescription(t('Id de la persona'))
        ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
        ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
        ->setDescription(t('UUID de la persona.'))
        ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['cnombre'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('Nombre'))
        ->setDescription(t('Nombre de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'max_length' => 40,
            'text_processing' => 0,
        ])
        ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['capellido1'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('Apellido 1'))
        ->setDescription(t('Apellido 1 de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'max_length' => 255,
            'text_processing' => 0,
        ])
        ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['capellido2'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('Apellido 2'))
        ->setDescription(t('Apellido 2 de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'max_length' => 255,
            'text_processing' => 0,
        ]);

    $fields['cnif'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('NIF/NIE'))
        ->setDescription(t('NIF/NIE de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'max_length' => 30,
            'text_processing' => 0,
        ]);

    $fields['dfecnac'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
        ->setLabel(t('Fecha de nacimiento'))
        ->setDescription(t('Fecha de nacimiento de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'datetime_type' => 'date'
        ])
        ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['ngenero'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_integer')
        ->setLabel(t('Género'))
        ->setDescription(t('Género de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'allowed_values' => [
                1 => 'Hombre',
                2 => 'Mujer',                    
            ],
        ])            
        ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['adireccion'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('address')
        ->setLabel(t('Dirección de residencia'))
        ->setDescription(t('Dirección de residencia de la persona'))
        ->setRequired(FALSE);

    $fields['ctelefono'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('Teléfono'))
        ->setDescription(t('Teléfono de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'max_length' => 15,
            'text_processing' => 0,
        ]);

    $fields['nestadocivil'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_integer')
        ->setLabel(t('Estado civil'))
        ->setDescription(t('Estado civil de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'allowed_values' => [
                1 => 'Soltero/a',
                2 => 'Casado/a',
                3 => 'Unión libre/de hecho',
                4 => 'Separado/a',
                5 => 'Divorciado/a',
                6 => 'Viudo/a',
            ],
        ])
        ->setDefaultValue(1);

    $fields['lbaja'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
        ->setLabel(t('Baja'))
        ->setDescription(t('Baja de la persona'))
        ->setDefaultValue(FALSE);

    $fields['dfechabaja'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
        ->setLabel(t('Fecha de baja'))
        ->setDescription(t('Fecha de baja de la persona'))
        ->setSettings([
            'datetime_type' => 'date'
        ])
        ->setRequired(FALSE);

return $fields;
}

And this is my StorageSchema:
class PersonasStorageSchema extends SqlContentEntityStorageSchema {

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getEntitySchema(ContentEntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $reset = FALSE) {
    $schema = parent::getEntitySchema($entity_type, $reset);

    $schema['personas']['indexes'] += [
          'personas_nombre' => ['capellido1', 'capellido2', 'cnombre'],
        ];
    
    return $schema;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getSharedTableFieldSchema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $storage_definition, $table_name, array $column_mapping) {
    $schema = parent::getSharedTableFieldSchema($storage_definition, $table_name, $column_mapping);
    $field_name = $storage_definition->getName();

    switch ($field_name) {

        case 'cnombre':
        case 'capellido1':
        case 'dfecnac':
        case 'nestadocivil':
        case 'ngenero':
            $schema['fields'][$field_name]['not null'] = TRUE;
            break;
        
        case 'cnif':
            $this->addSharedTableFieldIndex($storage_definition, $schema, FALSE);
            break;           
    }

    return $schema;
}}`

I want only and index for id (primary), uuid(unique), cnif (explicity added in my storageschema) and personas_nombre (explicity added with multiple fields). But, I don't know why, it creates more indexes for: dfecnac, ngenero, nestadocivil, dfechabaja.
How could I prevent it?

I've checked the field types of the fields mentioned and they all have indexes defined. Indexes of field types are merged with indexes on entity level. You can prevent it by using field types not using indexes. You can create your own field type based on a core field by extending the field plugin classes and overriding the schema() method. For example remove the indexes key in
Drupal\options\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ListIntegerItem::schema
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return [
      'columns' => [
        'value' => [
          'type' => 'int',
        ],
      ],
      'indexes' => [
        'value' => ['value'],
      ],
    ];
  }


Thanks. Following your suggestions, I have changed my PersonasStorageSchema in order to unset 'indexes' array, and then, indexs are not created. For example: case 'dfecnac': unset($schema['indexes']); break;
